# Segmentation fault when passing array

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The following simple c++ program always gives segmentation fault, which I cannot see the reason. This error goes away if I set `N2`=1000.

But I don't think the size of the lists is large at all. Commenting out `evolve`, I tried define 10 times larger arrays in the main function, which gives no error at all.

```
#include <iostream>

const int N1 = 481, N2 = 2000;

using std::cout; using std::endl;

void evolve(double* lista, double* listb){
    int ha = 10; ha++;
    cout << 88 << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    double list1[N1 * N2], list2[N1 * N2];
    evolve(list1, list2);
    cout << "End." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably a stack overflow.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis But I can't see what might be too larger here.

Comment: 481*2000*sizeof(double)*2 =  15392000

Comment: memset(list1,0x00,N1*N2);
memset(list2,0x00,N1*N2);

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I tried defining 10 times larger arrays in the main function, which gives no error at all. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Arrays defined inside a function (including `main`) are allocated on the stack, which is of limited size.  Arrays defined at global scope are not, and are effectively of unlimited size in 64 bit programs.